# Can't Get \xappto Working

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, etoolbox

I'm trying to learn how to use `\xappto`, and I've been working with this example. Why isn't this working? When I pass `after row=\noexpand\midrule` directly into `\codeforpgf{}` it works fine, but something is going wrong wen I use the `\xappto`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{pgfplotstable}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
    ColA, ColB, ColC
    0.17, 0.91, 0.67
    0.15, 0.17, 0.92
    0.48, 0.1, 0.28
\end{filecontents*}

\def\buildTable#1{%
    \def\temp{after row=\noexpand\midrule}%
    \def\codeforpgf{}%
    \expandafter\xappto\expandafter\codeforpgf\expandafter{\temp}%
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{#1}\rawdata%
    \xdef\theTable{\noexpand\pgfplotstabletypeset[\codeforpgf]}%
    \theTable{\rawdata}%    
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \buildTable
    {%CSV file
        test.csv%
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the reason for such a mess with expansions?

Comment: Avoid commands with "x" like `\xdef` or `\xappto` unless you know *exactly* that they will work. The "x" means "expand everything" and is not something you should normally do with complicated commands.

Comment: (Except for `\xapptocmd`, `\xpretocmd` and `\xpatchcmd` from the `xpatch` package, which don't perform this expansion.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

egreg and Ulrike Fisher are right. And in my opinion, this is a unnecessarily complicated and dangerous definition. `\buildTable` can be written much simpler:

```
\def\buildTable#1{%
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{#1}\rawdata%
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[after row=\midrule]{\rawdata}%
}%
```

But you want to learn about `\xappto`, so here an explanation what went wrong:

First, you don't need all the `\expandafter`s, because `\xappto` will expand `\temp` for you. But this is not much of a problem, because with the `\expandafter`s it's basically like writing `\xappto\codeforpgf{after row=\noexpand\midrule}` instead. The main problem is the second expansion in `\xdef`.

When `\noexpand` is expanded, it copies the next token (in your case `\midrule`) back into the input stream without expansion. After this, the `\noexpand` is gone, it did its work. This expansion is done in `\xappto`. So instead of writing

```
\def\temp{after row=\noexpand\midrule}%
\def\codeforpgf{}%
\xappto\codeforpgf{\temp}%
```

you could have written

```
\def\codeforpgf{after row=\midrule}%
```

which would have the same result **and the same errors**. The latter because now `\xdef` will try to expand `\midrule` outside of a table, which is not a good idea. With

```
\def\codeforpgf{after row=\noexpand\midrule}%
```

the `\xdef` would work as expected. In order to get the `\midrule` through both expansions un-expanded, it is necessary to write

```
\def\temp{after row=\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\midrule}%
```

In your macro, you could have also used `\appto` instead of `\xappto` to make it work.

In the code below I inserted a few `\show`s. `\show\somemacro` will show the definition of `\somemacro` in the log file. For example,
`\buildTableC` will write

```
> \temp=macro:
->after row=\noexpand \noexpand \noexpand \midrule .
```

to the log. With this you can see how the `\noexpand`s vanish. Search for the many `X`, I wrote to the log with `\typeout`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{pgfplotstable}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
    ColA, ColB, ColC
    0.17, 0.91, 0.67
    0.15, 0.17, 0.92
    0.48, 0.1, 0.28
\end{filecontents*}

% better and easier definition of \buildTable
\def\buildTableA#1{%
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{#1}\rawdata%
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[after row=\midrule]{\rawdata}%
}%

% unnecessarily complicated and dangerous definition, using \appto instead of \xappto
\def\buildTableB#1{%
    \def\temp{after row=\noexpand\midrule}%
    \def\codeforpgf{}%
    \typeout{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \string\buildTableB}%
    \show\temp
    \show\codeforpgf
    \appto\codeforpgf{\temp}%
    \show\codeforpgf
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{#1}\rawdata%
    \xdef\theTable{\noexpand\pgfplotstabletypeset[\codeforpgf]}%
    \show\theTable
    \theTable{\rawdata}%    
}%

% unnecessarily complicated and dangerous definition
\def\buildTableC#1{%
    \def\temp{after row=\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\midrule}%
    \def\codeforpgf{}%
    \typeout{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \string\buildTableC}%
    \show\temp
    \show\codeforpgf
    \xappto\codeforpgf{\temp}%
    \show\codeforpgf
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{#1}\rawdata%
    \xdef\theTable{\noexpand\pgfplotstabletypeset[\codeforpgf]}%
    \show\theTable
    \theTable{\rawdata}%    
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \buildTableA{test.csv}

    \buildTableB{test.csv}

    \buildTableC{test.csv}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```